# How do I freeze only visible columns in SWT NatTable

Tags: nattable

I currently have column/row freezing working to the point where I can right click on a column/row header, and click 'freeze' and it will freeze the column I clicked on and all columns to the left. The issue is that if I scroll to the right, and click on say column index 20 (really any index that hides indices on the left) it will freeze ALL columns below that index, which causes the table to snap back to index 0, and not allowing me to scroll (because more columns than shown are frozen). How can I freeze only VISIBLE columns to the left of the one I clicked on? I came upon the IFreezeCoordinatesProvider and tried to do some cheeky stuff with that but to no avail. Below is my custom configuration to create the right click menu, which contains the command for freezing. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
public class ColumnHeaderRightClickConfiguration extends AbstractUiBindingConfiguration{

private final ViewportLayer viewportLayer;
private final CompositeFreezeLayer freezeLayer;
private Menu rightClickMenu;

private int localColumnIndex;
private int columnIndex;

private FreezeColumnCommand freezeCommand;

public ColumnHeaderRightClickConfiguration(final NatTable natTable, ViewportLayer viewportLayer, CompositeFreezeLayer freezeLayer){
    this.viewportLayer = viewportLayer;
    this.freezeLayer = freezeLayer;
    this.rightClickMenu = createRightClickMenu(natTable).build();

    natTable.addDisposeListener(new DisposeListener(){
        @Override
        public void widgetDisposed(DisposeEvent e) {
            rightClickMenu.dispose();
        }

    });
}

private PopupMenuBuilder createRightClickMenu(NatTable natTable){

    Menu menu = new Menu(natTable);

    MenuItem freezeLeft = new MenuItem(menu, SWT.NONE);
    freezeLeft.setText("Freeze");

    MenuItem unfreeze = new MenuItem(menu, SWT.NONE);
    unfreeze.setText("Unfreeze");
    unfreeze.setEnabled(false);

    freezeLeft.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener(){
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            System.out.println(columnIndex);
            freezeCommand = new FreezeColumnCommand(freezeLayer, columnIndex-1, true);
            natTable.doCommand(freezeCommand);

            freezeLeft.setEnabled(false);
            unfreeze.setEnabled(true);
        }
        @Override
        public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e){}
    });

    unfreeze.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener(){
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            natTable.doCommand(freezeCommand);

            unfreeze.setEnabled(false);
            freezeLeft.setEnabled(true);
        }
        @Override
        public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e) {}
    });

    return new PopupMenuBuilder(natTable, menu);
}

@Override
public void configureUiBindings(UiBindingRegistry uiBindingRegistry) {
    MouseEventMatcher matcher = new MouseEventMatcher(SWT.NONE, GridRegion.COLUMN_HEADER, MouseEventMatcher.RIGHT_BUTTON){
        @Override
        public boolean matches(NatTable natTable, MouseEvent event, LabelStack regionLabels){
            if (super.matches(natTable, event, regionLabels)){
                localColumnIndex = natTable.getColumnPositionByX(event.x);
                columnIndex = viewportLayer.localToUnderlyingColumnPosition(localColumnIndex);
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
    };
    uiBindingRegistry.registerMouseDownBinding(matcher, new ColumnPopupMenuAction(rightClickMenu));
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now the `FreezeColumnCommand` does not support the requested feature. Only the `FreezeSelectionCommand` is able to perform a freeze operation by moving the left side columns that are not visible outside the viewport. The reason is that the corresponding `FreezeColumnStrategy` does not take the current viewport state into account on calculating the freeze coordinates. This is surely something to fix in NatTable and I created a ticket for this: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=504489

Until this is fixed in NatTable you can use the `FreezeHelper` directly. This exposes the internal calculation and handling of freezing into your code which typically should be avoided, but right now it would be a workaround.

Additionally your menu configuration does not follow the NatTable guidelines. There are many things you are doing that doesn't fit, e.g. creating your own menu but using the PopupMenuBuilder. Here is the code that works with NatTable 1.4.

```
public class ColumnHeaderRightClickConfiguration extends AbstractUiBindingConfiguration {

    private Menu rightClickMenu;

    private boolean frozen = false;

    public ColumnHeaderRightClickConfiguration(
            NatTable natTable,
            CompositeFreezeLayer compositeFreezeLayer,
            FreezeLayer freezeLayer,
            ViewportLayer viewportLayer,
            SelectionLayer selectionLayer) {
        this.rightClickMenu = new PopupMenuBuilder(natTable)
                .withMenuItemProvider("freeze", new IMenuItemProvider() {

                    @Override
                    public void addMenuItem(NatTable natTable, Menu popupMenu) {
                        MenuItem freezeLeft = new MenuItem(popupMenu, SWT.NONE);
                        freezeLeft.setText("Freeze");

                        freezeLeft.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
                            @Override
                            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent event) {
                                int columnPosition = MenuItemProviders.getNatEventData(event).getColumnPosition();
                                int pos = LayerUtil.convertColumnPosition(natTable, columnPosition, selectionLayer);
                                // this should be the solution
                                // if (compositeFreezeLayer.doCommand(new FreezeColumnCommand(compositeFreezeLayer, pos, true))) {
                                //     ColumnHeaderRightClickConfiguration.this.frozen = true;
                                // }

                                int coordCol = 0;
                                coordCol = viewportLayer.getScrollableLayer()
                                        .getColumnPositionByX(viewportLayer.getOrigin().getX());
                                if (coordCol > 0
                                        && coordCol >= pos) {
                                    coordCol = pos;
                                }

                                PositionCoordinate topLeftPosition = new PositionCoordinate(freezeLayer, coordCol, -1);
                                PositionCoordinate bottomRightPosition = new PositionCoordinate(freezeLayer, pos, -1);

                                FreezeHelper.freeze(freezeLayer, viewportLayer, topLeftPosition, bottomRightPosition);
                                ColumnHeaderRightClickConfiguration.this.frozen = true;
                            }
                        });

                    }
                })
                .withMenuItemProvider("unfreeze", new IMenuItemProvider() {

                    @Override
                    public void addMenuItem(NatTable natTable, Menu popupMenu) {
                        MenuItem unfreeze = new MenuItem(popupMenu, SWT.NONE);
                        unfreeze.setText("Unfreeze");

                        unfreeze.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
                            @Override
                            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent event) {
                                natTable.doCommand(new UnFreezeGridCommand());
                                ColumnHeaderRightClickConfiguration.this.frozen = false;
                            }
                        });
                    }
                })
                .withEnabledState("freeze", new IMenuItemState() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean isActive(NatEventData natEventData) {
                        return !ColumnHeaderRightClickConfiguration.this.frozen;
                    }
                })
                .withEnabledState("unfreeze", new IMenuItemState() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean isActive(NatEventData natEventData) {
                        return ColumnHeaderRightClickConfiguration.this.frozen;
                    }
                })
                .build();

        natTable.addDisposeListener(new DisposeListener() {
            @Override
            public void widgetDisposed(DisposeEvent e) {
                ColumnHeaderRightClickConfiguration.this.rightClickMenu.dispose();
            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public void configureUiBindings(UiBindingRegistry uiBindingRegistry) {
        MouseEventMatcher matcher = new MouseEventMatcher(
                SWT.NONE,
                GridRegion.COLUMN_HEADER,
                MouseEventMatcher.RIGHT_BUTTON);
        uiBindingRegistry.registerMouseDownBinding(
                matcher,
                new PopupMenuAction(this.rightClickMenu));
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, thank you! On a side note, I may have discovered a bug. When clicking to freeze say index 150, it will cause the non-frozen viewport portion on the right to jump forward by the amount of indices hidden on the left, e.g. if 145-150 were visible at the time of freezing, it would jump by 145 indices. I remedied this by just calling
    viewportLayer.setOriginX(0);
When the correct solution is implemented for my previous problem, that line should probably be added in the freeze() method.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that too. With the latest SNAPSHOT build (>=#563) it should work as expected.